# SOAP XML with Django

Tags: python, django, soap

I'm doing hardcoded SOAP requests today. And trying to find any lib/app for django to have a more simple clean way to make these requests.

Do you have any suggestions for a good one?

This is an example of a first request to get a sessionID. So you get a feeling how I'm doing it today.

```
    request = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'
    request = request + ' <soapenv:Body>'
    request = request + '<login>'
    request = request + '<userName>USERNAME</userName>'
    request = request + '<pw>PASSWORD</pw>'
    request = request + '</login>'
    request = request + '</soapenv:Body>'
    request = request + '</soapenv:Envelope>'

    request = u"""""" + request + """""".format()

    encoded_request = request.encode('utf-8')

    headers = {"Host": ""+ IP +"",
               "Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=UTF-8",
               "Content-Length": str(len(encoded_request)),
               "SOAPAction": ""}

    response = requests.post(url="http://"+ url +"/MessageService",
                             headers=headers,
                             data=encoded_request,
                             verify=False)

    return response.content
```

From this I get a XML response that I extract a sessionID that I need for further requests in the same amtter as this one.

Anyway. Suggestions are highly appreciated =)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try [zeep](http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/)? I think it is the best and most up to date Python SOAP client.

It is much cleaner than doing hardcoded SOAP requests.

Comment: Hi, I've been trying at this zeep for almost a week now. It's not working with zeep. The documentation is veru poor and hard to follow with nearly none examples. Also tried several times with help from stackoverflow, but no responses to my questions.

Is there any other app/lib that have good documentation? Maybe also a community that live.

Comment: What kind of issues did you have with zeep? You can just follow the example shown on the top of the main page and make sure that you are passing the right URL. There is another library the ``suds-jurko``. Personally, I had some issues with ``suds-jurko`` and I had to send raw XML for some more complex calls and that's why I switched to zeep.